# Developing a User Authentication in DreamWeaver CS6

Tags: authentication, content-management-system, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

I have actually set up and implemented a couple dynamic webpages for my website that involve adding news feeds and other media sources everyday with certain filters.

For right now, only I know the exact address of my admin menu for the CMS, but really anybody could access it right now since it isn't password protected.

I've looked into how to set up a User Authentication Restriction in Adobe's DreamWeaver CS6, but I keep hitting the same bump in the road in trying to do so.

I have my login.php page in front of me, and with the "password" field selected, I click on Server Behaviors > Add a Server Behavior > User Authentication > Login User. But this is where it gets hairy

I have the ability to pull up the database I have been using locally which involves about 4 separate columns (none of which have anything to do with a username/password), but when I go to select from the table which columns are used to verify the "username" and "password" field on my login.php page, there quite simply isn't a corresponding column to select.

I know there must be another way to set up in the database or in a separate database the values for my Logon, but I am not sure where. Anyone have any clue how to set this up so I can create a User Logon for my webpages? I tried granting my username all privileges and giving it a password in phpMyAdmin for this certain database I have been talking about but it did not help in creating the User Login (unless I missed something again in creating this password/granting all privileges).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your database username up with an index value in your table. It's an option other wise a key icon.

Unique I'd auto increment + username indexed + password varchar+ timestamp timestamp + reference1